# field not inserting using trigger

Tags: trigger

I created a trigger in the Events Object so that I can pull all the names under the 'Name' field and 'Attendees' field in the Events page and then insert those values in a custom text field. But I'm having issues when trying to insert the values into the new field. I can't figure out why it won't update the new field. Can someone please help me with my problem. I'm new to salesforce and slowly trying to tackle all these obstacles I'm hitting and I'm stuck.

```
trigger ContactMergeHelp on Event (before update) {
    Set<Id> relIds = new Set<Id>();    
    List<Event> lstAdd = new List<Event>();

    for(EventRelation iRel : [SELECT Id, RelationId, EventId FROM EventRelation where EventId IN :trigger.new AND isInvitee = true]){           
            relIds.add(iRel.RelationId);      
    }

    for(Id ewe: relIds){
        for(Event eVent : trigger.new)
        {
            for(Contact eC: [Select Name from Contact where Id = :ewe])
            {
                eVent.NewField__c +=  eC.Name + '; ';   
            }

            for(Lead eL: [Select Name from Lead where Id = :ewe])
            {
                eVent.NewField__c +=  eL.Name + '; ' ; 
            }                   
        } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Since you are new to Salesforce, I would recommend looking through apex best practices, specifically writing code for bulk record. In your case the issue can be that the queries are not returning anything and it is not going to where you are setting fields. A debug log will be really helpful

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to update? Are you getting any error message or it just won't update? Also, I see lot of issues with the code. Refer these links to understand governor limits and apex best practices. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm

Comment: @ManishAnand, I'm trying to update a custom field I created called 'eVent.NewField__c' and append the values from the Name and Attendees fields of the event. This field should also get updated each time the record is changed. For some reason it wont update my custom field. I put a System.debug('Contact Names: ' + eC.Name) and a value does show up.